# How to remove spaces between icons when middle icons is not shown

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have 4 icons in column, i do not want to show 2 middle icons in some condition but their space still remained.

I want remove those space:

[image]

```
return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        iconsModel[0].selected // decide to show icon or not
            ? Container(
                child:Image.asset(
                        iconsModel[0].iconAdress,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        color: widget.currentColorRow.withOpacity(0.5),
                      ),
              )
            : Container(),
        iconsModel[1].selected // decide to show icon or not
            ? Container(
                child:Image.asset(
                        iconsModel[1].iconAdress,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        color: widget.currentColorRow.withOpacity(0.5),
                      ),
              )
            : Container(),
        iconsModel[2].selected // decide to show icon or not
            ? Container(
                child:Image.asset(
                        iconsModel[2].iconAdress,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        color: widget.currentColorRow.withOpacity(0.5),
                      ),
              )
            : Container(),
        iconsModel[3].selected // decide to show icon or not
            ? Container(
                child:Image.asset(
                        iconsModel[3].iconAdress,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        color: widget.currentColorRow.withOpacity(0.5),
                      ),
              )
            : Container(),
```

How can i remove these space when middle icons are not shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution is to use `MainAxisAlignment.start` on `Column` But if you want the `spaceBetween` then use List of Widget and add/remove items from it based on  `iconsModel[any].selected`.